# Detecting danger in tweets

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Looking for APIs, methods, research, etc on the subject of deciding whether a tweet (a string, really) conveys a mood of danger.

For example:

- Danger: "this house across the street is on fire!!
- Not danger: "this girl is on fire! love this song"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is little research done on the *particular* problem of detecting danger, but there are a few research papers describing methods to detect natural hazards. Your example is reminiscent of the title of one of them: [Finding Fires with Twitter](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/U13-1011). Another research that you may find useful is [Emergency Situation Awareness: Twitter Case Studies](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-11818-5_19).

In general, however, the best approach to solve such a problem is through supervised classification, very similar to how sentiment analysis is (or rather, was, because there are more sophisticated machine learning paradigms like [Deep Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) being applied nowadays) done.

The essence is to label documents (in your case, tweets) into "danger" and "not danger". This labeling is done by human experts. Ideally, they should be well versed in the language and the domain. So, using native English speakers who know the colloquialisms of Twitter would be perfect annotators for this task.

Once adequate number of documents have been labeled, the baseline (i.e. the basic approach) is usually achieved by creating n-gram word vectors as feature vectors, and running SVM. If you are not aware of machine learning details, please read up on them before doing this.

Comment: Spent a couple hours downloading tweets and classifying them manually... Now I'm using a Naive Bayesian Classifier and it seems to work good!